# How and in which folder should I store the file? The file will need to delete and add data

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How and in which folder should I store the file(xml)? The file will need to delete and add data using "linq to xml"

I use Visual studio. Cross-Platform project.

Comment: Why not use a database instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is not a user document (like a Word doc), but rather a settings file, then the most appropriate place to store it would be in the user's application data folder, which is one of the folders under C:\Users\username\AppData

You would find this as follows...

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

However, a bit more information about what you're actually trying to achieve might help you get a better answer.

Hope that helps